# How to write contents of System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection to file?

Tags: c#, stringcollection

I have had no luck searching the obvious places for an answer to why using File.WriteAllLines(); doesn't work when outputting a StringCollection:

```
static System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection infectedLog = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
```

Omitting code here that has populated infectedLog.......

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\CustomSearchInfectedFiles.txt", infectedLog);
```

Could anyone either tell me what I am doing wrong, or point me in the direction of an explanation that will please?

Comment: _How_ does it not work? What is the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `File.WriteAllLines` expects an `IEnumerable<string>` (or a `string[]`) whereas `StringCollection` only implements `IEnumerable` (note the lack of generic type). Try the following:

```
using System.Linq;
...
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\CustomSearchInfectedFiles.txt", infectedLog.Cast<string>());
```

Comment: Perfect. You're a star. Thank-you! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\CustomSearchInfectedFiles.txt", infectedLog.Cast<string>());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that StringCollection is a really cold collection.  It does not implement IEnumerable<T>, and it is not an array, so there is no overload of WriteAllLines for it.

You can do this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(theFileName, infectedLog.Cast<string>());
```

Or, you could switch to a more modern collection type, like a List<string>.

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"testfile.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var line in sc)
            {
                w.WriteLine(line);
            }
            w.Close();
        }
```